# Изменение позиционирования блока с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

на странице есть блок с фиксированным позиционированием. 
смещен по левому краю экрана на `-100%`:
нужно чтобы после загрузки страницы, через `500ms` его позиционирование становилось `left: 0%`, со скоростью `500ms`. а затем через `5s` принимало свое первоначальное положение. С помощью присвоения класса знаю как сделать. Но мне нужно именно свойство `left` перезаписать. Пробовал вот так, но опыта маловато:

```js
$('.messages')(function ($) {
var left = -2000;
$('.messages').css('left', left);
 )};
```

```css
.messages {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 150;
    top: 40px;
    max-width: 600px;
    left: 00%;
    background: #97E253;
    padding: 5px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages">Сообщение
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.messages').stop().animate({left: 0}, 500);` + `setTimeout(имя_функции, 500)`

Comment: времени на развернутый ответ нет. подсказка — https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".topBlock").css("lett", "0px")
```

Единицы измерения забыли.
Интервал задавать - setTimeout () , почитайте, там нет ни че сложного

Comment: при указании значения `0` единицы можно не ставить, так как `0em`=`0px`=`0`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   var regLeftFnc = function(elem, left) {
      $(elem).css('left', left);
   };
   var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      regLeftFnc('.messages', '0');
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(function(){
         regLeftFnc('.messages', '-100%');
         clearTimeout(timeout);
      }, 5000);
   }, 500);
});
```

```css
.messages {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 150;
    top: 40px;
    max-width: 600px;
    left: -100%;
    background: #97E253;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages">Сообщение
</div>
```